# get the git commit hash of the last commit which affected files not listed in a .gitignore-like file

Tags: bash, git, shell

I am using a CI/CD system to automate the building of Docker Images from a git repository. The Image Tag of the image corresponds to the short (i.e. 8-characters) hash of the corresponding git commit, e.g. `myimage:123456ab`.

The repository contains source code that gets packaged in the Docker Image and stuff like documentation and deployment configuration that is excluded using a [`.dockerignore`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file) file (similar to `.gitignore`).

While the process works in general, it leads to rebuilding and redeploying Docker Images that are absolute identical, because the only changes were made to files that did not become part of the Image (e.g. the repositories README).

Using only the shell (bash in this case), git and standard *nix tools, is there a way to get the short hash of the latest commit that changed a file which is **not** ignored by the `.dockerignore` file? This should as well cover removing a non-ignored file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this through a combination of `git log` and `git show`.

The following script will go backwards through the revision history and find the first commit to have a change that would not be ignored by `.dockerignore`

```
for commit in $(git log --pretty=%H)
do
  # Get the changed file names for the commit. 
  # Use `sed 1d` to remove the first line, which is the commit description
  files=$(git show $commit --oneline --name-only | sed 1d)
  if docker-check-ignore $files
  then
     echo $commit
     exit 0
  fi
done
exit 1
```

And then you could define `docker-check-ignore` as a script like the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
DIR=$(mktemp -d)
pushd $DIR
# Set up a temporary git repository so we can use 
# git check-ignore with .dockerignore
git init
popd
cp .dockerignore $DIR/.gitignore
pushd $DIR
git check-ignore $@
# Store the error code
ERROR=$? 
popd
rm -rf $DIR
exit $ERROR
```

I will leave reducing the number of file system operations rather than creating/removing a directory for each commit.

Comment: thanks for the answer! your `git log` invocation makes it quite hard for me to check where the list of files ends and the next commit starts, any idea? Additionally, the awk script complains about syntax errors at both left curly brackets. Do you know what the problem might be?

Comment: @muffel I rewrote the answer to make this simpler. You can use `git show` to get per-commit lists of changes. This may be slightly less efficient, but it is significantly easier/more readable to implement.

Answer (score 1):

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

declare -a ign_table=()

# Populates ign_table with patterns from .dockerignore
while IFS= read -r line || [[ ${line} ]]; do
  ign_table+=("${line}")
done < <(sed '/^#/d;/^$/d' .dockerignore)

is_docker_ignored() {

  locale -i ignore=1 # false, default not ignored

  for ign_patt in "${ign_table[@]}"; do

    # If pattern starts with ! it is an exception rule
    # when filename match !pattern, do not ignore it
    # shellcheck disable=SC2053 # $ign_patt must not use quotes to match wildcards
    if [[ ${ign_patt} =~ ^\!(.*) ]] && [[ ${1} == ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ]]; then
      return 1 # false: no need to check further patterns, file not ignored
    fi

    # Normal exclusion pattern, if file match,
    # shellcheck disable=SC2053 # $ign_patt must not use quotes to match wildcards
    if [[ ${1} == $ign_patt ]]; then
      ignore=0 # true: it match an ignore pattern, file may not be ignored if it later matches an exception pattern
    fi
  done

  return "${ignore}"
}

while IFS= read -r file
do
  is_docker_ignored "${file}" && continue # File is in .dockerignore
  commit_hash="$(git rev-list --all -1 "${file}")"
  printf '%s\n' "${commit_hash:0:8}"
done < <(git ls-files)
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, I like the idea of not relying on git here. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work with re-inclusions (`*`, `!test.txt`).

Comment: @muffel I added support for `!do-not-igore-me`, `!` exception rules as [documented here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file).